# Trying to send laptops current position to server and display on Google maps

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

Hi as the question says i'm trying to send my laptops current position using geolocation  to my website so that it can display its current location on a Google map. My problem is so far I can only get it to display the servers position, and getting some form of script that runs on the laptop to send to the server is where i'm in trouble, just looking to see if anyone has any ideas how to approach this, as its causing me some difficulty thanks

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: coords,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById("mapContainer"), 
            mapOptions
        );
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: coords,
            map: map,
            title: "Your current location!"
        });
    });
} else {
    alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you aren't giving any code that you have a problem with, I might as well just give you a link to the official Google Maps Gelocation API website page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/.

Comment: Hey I updated with the code that is running on the server. This works perfectly is shows location and everything on a Google map, the problem is its showing the servers location and not my laptop, what Im thinking is if there was a way to change the variables position.coords.latitude; and position.coords.longitude; with ones from my laptop it would work, but again im not sure how to get this to work

Comment: @Jack W What server's location?

Comment: This code runs inside my websites html code, which runs on a local server, so when it comes to tracking because its in the html its locating the server and not the machine, what id hope to do is to maybe have a script on my laptop that constantly runs in the background and simply updates the current position with whatever the laptops is.

Comment: So you want the laptop to keep updating it's position to a map that other people can see?

Comment: Yes exactly, in practicality it would only be me that would see it, as its on my own built website, but yes thats the idea

Comment: Well, this would most likely be only possible with a software, unless you want to keep the website open at all times. I will research this, as it could be very interesting.

Comment: Great thanks for your help, the idea actually came about when a laptop of mine was stolen, and I know there are software solutions for this, but had done some programming before so thought I'd do my own, so far it hasnt been as easy as I had first planned, but hopefully I can figure something out, thanks again